# How to use a background image in ASP.Net control <asp:PasswordStrength>

Tags: asp.net

Can a "asp:PasswordStrength" control be customized to show different images for different "StrengthStyles="weak; average; strong" (separate image for each strength).

I am not able to upload a sample image as I am a new user. Sorry for that.

Kindly help,
Thanks,
Eswar

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [StrengthStyles](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/PasswordStrength/PasswordStrength.aspx) property to provide a list of CSS classes that will be applied to the indicator depending on the current password's strength. Then, you can use the [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/background-image) CSS property to associate an image with each class:

```
.weak {
    background-image: url(images/weak.png);
}

.average {
    background-image: url(images/average.png);
}

.strong {
    background-image: url(images/strong.png);
}

<asp:PasswordStrength ID="yourPasswordStrength" runat="server"
    TargetControlID="yourTextBox" StrengthStyles="weak;average;strong" />
```

Comment: Thanks Fréd. Will try that and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to display it as a bar indicator you can also apply backgrounds to them.  See the following article for sample code...

http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/ajax-password-strength-control